# How to send github OAuth data to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, github-api

I need to implement a github authorization and later send received data (JSON) to the client.

I found this tutorial http://shiya.io/how-to-do-3-legged-oauth-with-github-a-general-guide-by-example-with-node-js/

In that tutorial developer shows us this way: **"/"** -> "/login" -> "/redirect" -> **"/user"(data here)**

But i need: **"/"** -> "/login" -> "/redirect" -> **"/"(data here)**

Because the client is supposed to uses simple SPA(react).

What i have now:

```
    require('dotenv').config();
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const session = require('express-session');
    const request = require('request');
    const qs = require('querystring');
    const url = require('url');
    const randomString = require('randomstring');
    const csrfString = randomString.generate();

    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
    const redirect_uri = process.env.HOST + '/redirect';

    app.use(express.static('views'));

    app.use(
      session({
        secret: randomString.generate(),
        cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
      })
    );

    app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
      if (req.session.access_token) {
        request.get(
          {
            url: 'https://api.github.com/user',
            headers: {
              Authorization: 'token ' + req.session.access_token,
              'User-Agent': 'Login-App'
            }
          },
          (error, response, body) => {
            res.send(body);
          }
        );
      }
    });

    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log('Server listening at port ' + port);
    });

    app.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    req.session.csrf_string = randomString.generate();
    const githubAuthUrl =
      'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?' +
      qs.stringify({
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        state: req.session.csrf_string,
        scope: 'user:email'
      });
    res.redirect(githubAuthUrl);
    });

    app.all('/redirect', (req, res) => {
      console.log('Request sent by GitHub: ');
      console.log(req.query);

      const code = req.query.code;
      const returnedState = req.query.state;

      if (req.session.csrf_string === returnedState) {
        request.post(
          {
            url:
              'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?' +
              qs.stringify({
                client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
                code: code,
                redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
                state: req.session.csrf_string
              })
          },
          (error, response, body) => {
            console.log('Your Access Token: ');
            console.log(qs.parse(body));
            req.session.access_token = qs.parse(body).access_token;

            res.redirect('/');
          }
        );
      } else {
        res.redirect('/');
      }
      console.log(redirect_uri);
    });
```

In this moment res.send(body); throws an error

```
    app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
      if (req.session.access_token) {
        request.get(
          {
            url: 'https://api.github.com/user',
            headers: {
              Authorization: 'token ' + req.session.access_token,
              'User-Agent': 'Login-App'
            }
          },
          (error, response, body) => {
            res.send(body);
          }
        );
      }
    });
```

Error:

```
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

It happens because I trying to set data for rendering after rendering.

So, my question:

**How i can to send data to a client and how get it on client side?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP uses a cycle that requires one response per request. When the client sends a request the server should send only one response back to client.

Your are sending two response `res.sendFile()` & `res.send()` for one request, So your code need to be changed as follows,

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.access_token) {
        request.get({
            url: 'https://api.github.com/user',
            headers: { Authorization: 'token ' + req.session.access_token, 'User-Agent': 'Login-App' }
        }, (error, response, body) => { res.send(body); }
        );
    } else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    }
});
```